# array of images in Jupyter Markdown

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

How can I show two pictures side by side in Jupyter Markdown?

```
from IPython.core.display import Image, display, HTML
Image('C:/Temp/Sketch1.jpg')
Image('C:/Temp/Sketch2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution implements HTML code in a markdown cell:

```
<table align='left'>
<tr>
<td><img src='images/jupyter.png' width='200' height='200'/></td>
<td><img src='images/jupyter.png' width='200' height='200'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The cell is run to render the result.
Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This one works for me. However I should learn why it is not functional when images have different specs

Comment: @Fardin What are the specs of your images?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/installation.html) and [`numpy`](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display
from PIL import Image


img1 = Image.open('C:/Temp/Sketch1.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('C:/Temp/Sketch2.jpg')
display(Image.fromarray(np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)))
```

You could define a function that takes multiple file names and displays all the images side by side:

```
def sidebyside(*args):
    imgs = np.concatenate([np.asarray(Image.open(x)) for x in args], axis=1)
    display(Image.fromarray(imgs))

sidebyside('C:/Temp/Sketch1.jpg', 'C:/Temp/Sketch2.jpg')
```

I hope this helps.